# How to Specify Assembly Information in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: dll, visual-studio-mac

Unlike in Visual Studio 2017, I am unable to add [assembly version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pI1J6.png) information to my dll files in Visual Studio for Mac.

I have updated the version field in [.csproj](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8eAy.png)

Comment: `PackageVersion` is for NuGet only.

Comment: Not sure why this question was down-voted.  As someone who's on a Mac AND new to Visual Studio, I was looking for the same information. A course that I'm going through talked about the same thing — viewing AssemblyInfo.cs properties, but that's nowhere to be found on VS for Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`PackageVersion` is for NuGet only.

You should set the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion]` and/or `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion]` attributes in code.

Comment: Thanks, I have added the following properties in .csproj:
`<AssemblyVersion></AssemblyVersion>`
`<FileVersion></FileVersion>`
`<Version></Version>`